# AttributeError: 'GetBuilder' object has no attribute 'with_additional'

Tags: python, weaviate

In Weaviate vector db I get an AttributeError: 'GetBuilder' object has no attribute 'with_additional'.
I want to get an id of an object

I want to get an id of an object. For that I have used with_additional, with a filter.

Comment: could you please provide more info?

Comment: I am trying here to get an id of a saved object in the db. Using a filter I can retrieve the object, but in order to update I need the id. something like this => query_result = (
  client.query
  .get("Article", "title")
  .with_additional(additional_props)
  .with_near_text(near_text_filter)
  .do()
)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that my weaviate client version was older. I have updated that and it solved the error that I had